# how to delay a painting in progress in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So I'm drawing lines in a JPanel and I want to have it pause for a second every time that it draws one. I have used other things like TimeUnit and Timer that I found looking around this website but so far I just can't get it to work. I have the JFrame all set up and ready to go and this is just the last piece. Also I was wondering if whatever method that works can be applied to other types of shapes and things instead of just lines.

```
public class Panel extends JPanel { 
  Color [] colors = {Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE, Color.RED,Color.YELLOW,Color.CYAN,Color.GREEN, Color.PINK,Color.ORANGE};
  Random r = new Random();
  int amount;   
  public Panel(int amount) {
      this.amount = amount;
  } 
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
      for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
          Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {      
                    g2.setColor(colors[r.nextInt(7)]);
                    g2.drawLine(r.nextInt(600), r.nextInt(600), r.nextInt(600), r.nextInt(600));
              }
             });
          timer.setRepeats(false);
          timer.start();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: The paint methods should never attempt to implement a long running task. There are basically two good ways to go about this, one is to store a list of all the lines that need to be painted each time paint is called (this is fastest for a few thousand lines, but then slows down), and the other is to draw each line to a buffered image (this is more work for every paint, till the effort of drawing each line individually, exceeds it). Which approach would you prefer to pursue?

Comment: @RakeshKR Please stop giving advice on Swing animation until you can explain ***why*** that advice is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is mine solution for your task

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Panel extends JPanel {
    Color[] colors = {Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN, Color.PINK, Color.ORANGE};

    Random r = new Random();

    int amount, actual;

    Color nextColor;

    int x1, y1, x2, y2;

    public Panel(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
        Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                nextColor = colors[r.nextInt(7)];
                x1 = r.nextInt(600);
                x2 = r.nextInt(600);
                y1 = r.nextInt(600);
                y2 = r.nextInt(600);
                repaint();
                if (++actual >= amount) {
                    Timer t = (Timer) evt.getSource();
                    t.stop();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (nextColor != null) {
            g.setColor(nextColor);
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frm = new JFrame("Lines");

                frm.add(new Panel(10));
                frm.setSize(700, 700);
                frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frm.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your printing isn't getting delayed but since you are writing timer.start() in for loop which gets executed much before two seconds and thus calling the next timer.start() and therefore it seems as if timer is not working.
I would recommend you to use another logic.And yes this method can be applied to other shapes too.

Answer (score -2):

you can add this to your code

```
public class Panel extends JPanel { 
Color [] colors = {Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE, Color.RED,Color.YELLOW,Color.CYAN,Color.GREEN, Color.PINK,Color.ORANGE};
Random r = new Random();
int amount; 
public Panel(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}   
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {      
                    g2.setColor(colors[r.nextInt(7)]);
                    g2.drawLine(r.nextInt(600), r.nextInt(600), r.nextInt(600), r.nextInt(600));
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
              }
           });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

you can also use `Thread.sleep(1000)` in place of TimeUnit.